# I have a calender control stuck on loading, but only in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webforms

I have a calendar control (from component one) that is stuck on loading... It doesn't do this in my dev environment in visual studio, but just when I publish it to our Azure instance.

It looks like it breaking after a certain amount of events. As you can see in the link examples below.

This link is stuck on loading: 
http://seraphimmobile.com/calendar2.aspx?cid=ca926097-d632-488a-9cdc-77627a85c0af&color=white&bckcolor=rgb%282%2c107%2c181%29&sd=-1&ed=30

This link works fine because I adjusted the parameters of it: http://seraphimmobile.com/calendar2.aspx?cid=ca926097-d632-488a-9cdc-77627a85c0af&color=white&bckcolor=rgb%282%2c107%2c181%29&sd=-1&ed=10

Here is my code behind on how I'm binding it:

```
            Session["C1EvCalSessionUsed"] = true;
            string sessionDataFileName = "~/" + String.Format("c1evcaldata{0}.xml", User.Identity.Name + Session.LCID + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString().Substring(12, 6).Replace("\\", ""));
            C1EventsCalendar1.DataStorage.DataFile = sessionDataFileName;

            IList<RemoteClimbingGetEventsBetweenDates.EventByDays> _eventspan = new List<RemoteClimbingGetEventsBetweenDates.EventByDays>();
            _eventspan = objeventspan.GetEventsBetweenDates(DateTime.Now.AddDays(_startdate), DateTime.Now.AddDays(_enddate), _commid, "");


            Event ev = new Event();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var _event in _eventspan)
            {

                ev.Id = _event.eventid.Trim();
                ev.Color = _backcolor;
                ev.Start = _event.eventstartdate.Date + _event.eventstarttime.TimeOfDay;
                ev.End = _event.eventenddate.Date + _event.eventendtime.TimeOfDay;
                ev.Description = _event.eventdesc.Replace(@"/", "").Trim();
                ev.Subject = _event.eventname.Replace(@"/", "").Trim(); 

                C1EventsCalendar1.DataStorage.AddEvent(ev);

            }
```

And here is my asp code:

```
            <cc1:C1EventsCalendar ID="C1EventsCalendar1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="800px" >
            </cc1:C1EventsCalendar>
```

**Again, this only happens in production.** I'm pretty stumped with it. Any help or event suggestions on where to look would be helpful. Component One's support on this matter hasn't been too great since it doesn't break in the dev environment.

Here is what as am doing with the parameters as ask:

```
List<string> Keys = new List<string>();
List<string> Values = new List<string>();
string _commid = "";
string _backcolor = "";
int _startdate = 10;
int _enddate = 60;
try
{
    //Gets the Intial URL with the values
    string URL = Request.Url.ToString();

    URL = URL + "?cid=ca926097-d632-488a-9cdc-77627a85c0af&color=white&bckcolor=rgb(2,107,181)&sd=-10&ed=30";

    //Splits the URL before and after the ?
    string[] StringArray = URL.Split('?');

    //splits each key and value into their own string
    string[] NameValuePairs = StringArray[1].Split('&');

    //split each key and value into separate strings
    foreach (string s in NameValuePairs)
    {
        string[] KeyAndValue = s.Split('=');
        Keys.Add(KeyAndValue[0]);
        Values.Add(KeyAndValue[1]);

    }

    //Do stuff with the ids

    _commid = Values[0].ToString();
    Session["COLOR"] = Values[1].ToString();
    _backcolor = Values[2].ToString();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Values[3].ToString()))
    {
        _startdate = Convert.ToInt32(Values[3].ToString());
        _enddate = Convert.ToInt32(Values[4].ToString());
    }
}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: can you provide code showing what you are doing with these parameters?

Comment: Yes, here is is. It was in the page_load event

Comment: have you looked at the objects coming back from `GetEventsBetweenDates`? it worked inconsistently in a few ranges under 20 events. sometimes 19 day span would work, and other times 15, but i set the startdate to a larger number. let me know what you find.

Comment: since it is a webapp, try to open F12 developer tool, and check "console" to see if there is any errors.

Comment: @terbubbs I looked through it. It doesn't seem weird at all. I use that web service for other things as well. I also tried switching out the web service for a simular one and still get the same reaction from the control. Again, this only happens once in the production environment not in dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a problem with a control I was using...